# C++: How do I create a vector of objects and insert an object in 3rd place?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a vector of objects and insert an object into 3rd place. I've been unsuccessful so far. Here's my code. I made an array and added couple of objects to it and then made a vector and loaded it with the array. Also to note, MobilniTelefon is child of Proizvod. Here's my code:

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "MobilniTelefon.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char letters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char x = letters[rand() % 26];

        const int SIZE = 6;
        MobilniTelefon Array[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            Array[i].setIme(string{ letters[rand() % 26] });
            Array[i].setBarKod(i);
            Array[i].setSifra(string{ letters[rand() % 26] });
            Array[i].setCena((rand() % 100) + 1);
            Array[i].setMarka(string{ letters[rand() % 26] });
            Array[i].setModel(string{ letters[rand() % 26] });
        }

        vector<MobilniTelefon> vec(Array, Array + SIZE);
        ostream_iterator<int> output(cout, " ");

        MobilniTelefon mobilniDefault;

        mobilniDefault.setIme("g");
        mobilniDefault.setBarKod(123314);
        mobilniDefault.setSifra("assadsad");
        mobilniDefault.setCena(24234);
        mobilniDefault.setMarka("Apple");
        mobilniDefault.setModel("iPhone");

        vec.insert(vec.begin() + 3, mobilniDefault);

        //copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), output);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Proizvod.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Proizvod
{
public:
    string ime;
    int bar_kod;
    string sifra;
    float cena;


    void setIme(string i) { ime = i; }
    void setBarKod(int b) { bar_kod = b; }
    void setSifra(string s) { sifra = s; }
    void setCena(float c) { cena = c; }

    string getIme() { return ime; }
    int getBarKod() { return bar_kod; }
    string getSifra() { return sifra; }
    float getCena() { return cena; }

    void info() {
        cout << "Ime proizvoda: " << getIme() << endl;
        cout << "Bar kod proizvoda: " << getBarKod() << endl;
        cout << "Sifra proizvoda: " << getSifra() << endl;
        cout << "Cena proizvoda: " << getCena() << endl;
    }

};
```

MobilniTelefon.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Proizvod.h"
#include <fstream >
#include <istream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class MobilniTelefon : public Proizvod
{

private:
    string marka;
    string model;

public:
    void setMarka(string ma) { marka = ma; }
    void setModel(string mo) { model = mo; }

    string getMarka() { return marka; }
    string getModel() { return model; }

    void info() {
        cout << "Ime proizvoda: " << getIme() << endl;
        cout << "Bar kod proizvoda: " << getBarKod() << endl;
        cout << "Sifra proizvoda: " << getSifra() << endl;
        cout << "Cena proizvoda: " << getCena() << endl;
        cout << "Marka proizvoda: " << getMarka() << endl;
        cout << "Model proizvoda: " << getModel() << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------" << endl << endl;
    }

    MobilniTelefon& operator=(MobilniTelefon& a) {
        ime = a.getIme();
        bar_kod = a.getBarKod();
        sifra = a.getSifra();
        cena = a.getCena();
        marka = a.getMarka();
        model = a.getModel();

        return *this;
    }
};
```

I guess that the error is in operator= in MobilniTelefon. Copy() doesn't also work with the same error.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'MobilniTelefon' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: That is _way_ too much code for a SO question. Please [debug](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the program 
[yourself first](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) and then ask a _specific_ question with a [mre]. Other useful links: [tour], [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: And get used to use pure English identifiers. You *will* at some point meet up with people not speaking your mother tongue (and if only here on SO) – and if these do not understand what classes, variables or functions are intended to, all they can do is guess – and err.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) accepts a `const` reference to value type, which can only be assigned to other `const` references.

Your `operator=`, though, accepts a non-const reference, so it cannot be used in overload resolution.

General solution: Make `operator=` accept a `const` reference.

Specific solution for your case: Just drop your custom `operator=` entirely! There are no types involved that require explicit manual memory management (`std::string` does so fine on its own, the other members are primitive types anyway), so the operator generated by default will be absolutely fine.

`std::copy` not working: [`std::ostream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) uses `operator<<` to print values to the stream. There is no such operator for your type – you might convert your `info` function into one:

```
//void info() 
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, MobilniTelefon const& t)
{
    // output t to s as you just as you did previously this to std::cout
    return s;
}
```

Instead of calling `info`, you could now do

```
MobilniTelefon t;
std::cout << t;
```

Apart from, you are using wrong template specialisation, should be:

```
//std::ostream_iterator<int> output(std::cout, " ");
std::ostream_iterator<MobilniTelefon> output(std::cout, " ");
```

Comment: Dropping oprator= works but function copy() still displays the saame error.

Comment: @Nikola Added some lines for `copy` as well.